# Don't use Interfaces in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in Unity I make use of interfaces. I set a logic for components which are totally different to each other.

**Examples:**

A car, a dog and a aircraft would implement `IMovable`. I can call `Move()` from each component but these components execute different code.

Same for `ISavable`, each component, that has to save data to the database could save the stuff when looping through all savables.

**The problem:**

Some people in forums say that interfaces are bad for Unity.

When destroying a gameobject and call its interface method this still gets executed.

No error would come up because `Destroy()` does not destroy objects. Unity as a C++ driven Engine would setup a C# wrapper for the objects. These objects just get a flag destroyed which is a bool.

Destroyed gameobjects will not get destroyed immediately, they will be destroyed later on at the end of the frame.

Until this end of the frame is not reached the method can still get called from the destroyed object.

The best way would be using abstract classes only and never use interfaces because of the bad behaviour coming up when destroying objects.

I tested this with a small example, I created the following scripts:

```
    public interface IIntfacable
    {
        void DoSomething();

        void DestroyComponent();
    }

    public class bar : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private IIntfacable i;

        private void Start()
        {
            i = FindObjectOfType<foo>().GetComponent<IIntfacable>();
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            i.DoSomething();
            i.DestroyComponent();
            i.DoSomething();
        }
    }

    public class foo : MonoBehaviour, IIntfacable
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            Debug.Log("=> DoSomething");
        }

        public void DestroyComponent()
        {
            Debug.Log("=> DestroyComponent");
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
```

When executing this code I get the following result

[image: Test]

**Workaround:**

I could create an abstract base class and choose between

```
public abstract void Foo();
```

and

```
public virtual void Bar()
{
   return;
}
```

but this might lead to overengineering. Because all Scripts would need this base class whether they need this method or not.

**Conclusion:**

Should I prevent using interfaces?

Comment: I don't get the question - who are those people that say `interface` is bad?

Comment: Some people in german Unity forums.

Comment: Also how is your solution with an `abstract` class different from the `interface` one and why is it a problem that objects get destroyed at the end of the frame?

Comment: They say: Until this end of the frame is not reached the method can still get called from the destroyed object.

Comment: And what did your own tests show? How exactly has this proven to be a problem? So far you have only stated what some other (anonymous) people have said (apparently without testing whether it is true?)

Comment: I would be surprised if the behavior is any different with an abstract class. Maybe you should implement some kind of IDisposable pattern and then throw an error if a method is accessed on the destroyed/disposed object.

Comment: I updated my question and show my test project

Comment: The same behavior would occur with an `abstract` class as well, wouldn't it? Also it seems very contrived, why exactly is this an issue for you?

Comment: Interfaces is great boosting option for your project is you understand SOLID architecture principles.

Comment: As @UnholySheep said the same behaviour would occur even when you are using a abstract class. The real question is: Why would you destroy the component but still try to use it? I think you have a problem with your class-design. Try to explain why you are doing this instead of explaining the resulting error.

Comment: FYI, another problem is: Unity cannot properly serialize scripts with instances of abstract/interface instances by default. [Source](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html) You can, however, do a workaround by using a [ISerializationCallbackReceiver](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ISerializationCallbackReceiver.OnBeforeSerialize.html) and a manual serialization.

Answer (score 1):

I am confident in saying there is no harm in using interfaces.

The underlying fear is about keeping track of unmanaged references, a problem which will still be there weather you are using interfaces, abstract classes or whatever. You simply have to make sure that your game code will not try to access any objects which have been `Destroy()`ed.

Basically, I just construct a collection of objects that I know are not destroyed in my scene, and remove them after destruction.

With risk of answering an [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), If you are scared to miss out on your reference count anyway or there is something in particular which wont allow creating such a list, there is not really any magic wand here, but there are a few precedent patterns in the .net framework with the `IDisposable` interface/pattern that may lead the way.

Many implementations of these patterns checks a flag in a few public-facing methods of the object. `IDisposable.Dispose()` would set the flag to true and throw an `ObjectDisposedException` on some public method if this is set to true, analog to `MissingReferenceException` in this case. Some patterns will then expose the flag `IsDisposed`, so that other objects that use the implementation can check instead of doing a try-catch on any access to the object. Your analog could be `IsDestroyed`, and you should set it in the override of [OnDestroy](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDestroy.html).

You could change your method update like this (well it's not really a use case, why would you try to use it after destroying it, but to show my point):

```
    private void Update()
    {
        i.DoSomething();
        i.DestroyComponent();
        if (!i.IsDestroyed) {
           // This will not be called
           i.DoSomething();
        }
    }
```

and implementation could be

```
public interface IIntfacable : IDestroyable
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public interface IDestroyable
{
    void DestroyComponent();
    bool IsDestroyed { get; }
}

public class foo : MonoBehaviour, IIntfacable
{
    bool IsDestroyed { get; private set; }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Debug.Log("=> DoSomething");
    }

    public void DestroyComponent()
    {
        Debug.Log("=> DestroyComponent");
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    public override OnDestroy() {
      base.OnDestroy();
      IsDestroyed = true; 
    }
}
```